# VBA Excel Mac Dictionary Class on Mac Get Keys() Attribute

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The Get Keys() attribute is slow with a decent sized data set.  Is there a way to assign keys without looping through each record individually?

I can only find examples of for or do loops to assign keys individually.

```
Public Property Get Keys() As String()

'Here is the existing code (status bar updated only so the user knows the
'program is still working).

    Dim vlist() As String, i As Long, myKey As Variant, myArr() As Variant, okVP As KeyValuePair, StatBar As String
    StatBar = Application.StatusBar

    If Me.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim vlist(0 To Me.Count - 1)        

        For i = LBound(vlist) To UBound(vlist)
            Set okVP = KeyValuePairs(i + 1)
            vlist(i) = okVP.Key
            If i Mod 5000 = 0 Then
                Application.StatusBar = StatBar & ": " & "Gathering Keys: " & Format(i, "#,##0") & " of " & Format(UBound(vlist), "#,##0")
'                Debug.Print i & " of " & UBound(vlist)
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next i
        Keys = vlist
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = StatBar
End Property
```

Current approach takes >5 min for ~135K records.

Comment: FWIW a `Property Get` member should be trivial code that runs instantaneously, without any side-effects on global or instance state, and doesn't raise any errors. This isn't it. Consider making it a `Function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't avoid iterating the items. Under Windows you could probably leverage `CopyMemory` Win32 API to bulk-copy arrays, but I wouldn't trust these functions to work on a Mac.

Consider swapping your `KeyValuePair`-based `Dictionary` with [Tim Hall's drop-in `Dictionary` replacement](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary).

Now, hard to tell without seeing the class' `[_NewEnum]` implementation and default member (you have those?), but as far as I can tell you're iterating an object collection with a `For...Next` loop - and that is the slowest possible way to iterate any object collection.

Object collections *want* to be iterated with `For Each...Next`. Just that, [could slash the run time by several orders of magnitude](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/).

Updating the `Application` UI and running `DoEvents` (even once every 5K iterations) is further slowing down the loop... and this isn't the kind of thing you want to be doing in a `Property Get` member anyway.

Looks like `KeyValuePairs` is a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects? 135K of them means quite a lot of overhead - in .NET a `KeyValuePair` is a `struct` (value type), not an `object` (reference type); they are optimized differently, and perform differently too. Regardless, if you have a collection of `KeyValuePair` objects, the fastest way to iterate them is with a `For Each` loop.

```
ReDim result(0 To KeyValuePairs.Count - 1)
Dim i As Long
Dim kvp As KeyValuePair
For Each kvp In KeyValuePairs
    result(i) = kvp.Key
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Moreover, because of how arrays work in VBA and all the headaches associated with *typed* arrays, I'd think *returning* one would be safer if wrapped in a `Variant` pointer, or "returned" through a `ByRef` parameter (but that wouldn't work for a `Property Get` member).

Comment: Thank you so very much!  Iterating with `For Each...Next` reduced the time to less than 5sec.  For what it's worth, Tim Hall's dictionary took much longer to populate than the one I had found on here in my case.

Comment: Interesting. Consider opening an issue on the VBA-Tools/Dictionary repository, since (AFAIK) that code is actively maintained, and performance improvements would greatly benefit the VBA community as a whole!